# Overriding META-INF\services\org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator of hibernate envers

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am working with hibernate envers (4.3.5 version). 
Using Conditional auditing (15.8. hibernate envers doc)
I inherited EnversIntegrator creating my own customerEnversIntegrator.
for making envers to use this one, I added to META-INF\services\org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator the customerEnversIntegrator path.
it worked fine!
When i left it as default, but changed the application META-INF\services\org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator to point the customerEnversIntegrator was not used fully. so it actually didn't work
But i don't want this declaration to be in the jar level. i need to override it from the application. cause as a project - i can't control the jar, it could be updated and etc.

Any ideas how to override this file without changing anything in the Jar?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more specifically, I can only answer generally.

It shouldn't matter where you place your ServiceLoader file, just as long as that file is on the classpath during Hibernate bootstrap and that the contents point to a class which is also visible on the classpath.

It's probably worth noting that in Hibernate 6, I am looking to introduce a much more streamlined approach for conditional auditing where users can make use of entity-specific listeners (think JPA style entity listeners).  This removes the need to override any listener and can easily be plug-n-play applied to any entity on an as-needed basis.